# How to set a img next to a p element css?

Tags: html, css

i am making a website for school. The images need to float right with some `<p>` text to left of it but cant make it work. Who can help me, see img for clearence. Here is some code:

```css
.img-inno {
  float: right;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<header class="inno"> Innovation 1, Running
</header>
<p> One of the best sporting technoligies out is a treadmill to determine which running shoes you need. </p>
<p> You will walk a couple of 100 meters and a screen will show how you place you foot in the shoes you have tested. </p>
<p> Based on that you can choose new choes and will determine again if the shoes fit. </p>
Eventually you will have some good data which shoes will fit the best. The data will be sent via email.
<footer>
  <p> These shops are everywhere! In the USA and The Netherlands, you name it! </p>
  <a href="https://www.run4free.nl/"> More info? Click here</a>
</footer>

<a href="https://21run.com/eu/">
  <img class="img-inno" id="img1" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/male-athlete-running-on-tartan-track-royalty-free-image-1624297569.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.245xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="Running, copyright belongs to runner's world">
</a>
</article>





<article>
  <header class="inno"> Innovation 2, Bowling
  </header>
  <p>This one could be a little bit silly, but it is a good innovation. I am talking about the Computerized Scoring Bowling.</p>
  <p> A computer will focus on the score, while you can focus on the bowling aspect and don't have to count your scores. </p>
  <p>These small innovations have a impact about our daily life without you aven noticing.</p>

  <footer>
    Fun Fact: The risk of a false score went down drasticly after this invention.
    <a href="https://www.bowlingcentrum.nl/">Make a reservation for bwoling here. </a>
  </footer>
  <a href="https://www.etsy.com/nl/listing/1052730525/aangepaste-airbrushed-bowling-ball?gpla=1&gao=1&">
    <img class="img-inno" src="https://cdn.bleacherreport.net/images_root/slides/photos/000/995/723/83452843_display_image.jpg?1307417974" alt="Bowling, Copyright belongs to bleacherreport.com">
  </a>
</article>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to put the element that you want the text to float around, _before_ the text in source code order.

Comment: Offtopic: `text-align: left` does nothing on an image. You can remove that.

Answer (score 1):

As c.m. noted it is better to do it with CSS Flexbox.

Check out the following example to get an idea of how it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        article {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            /*flex-wrap: wrap;
            Use this if you want the images to wrap under the text for smaller screen sizes*/ 
        }
        
        .left {
            flex-grow: 3;
            flex-shrink: 1;
            flex-basis: auto;
        }

        .right {
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
            flex-basis: auto;
        }

        .img-inno {
            max-width: 200px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <div class="left">
            <header class="inno">
                Innovation 1, Running
            </header>
            <p> One of the best sporting technoligies out is a treadmill to determine which running shoes you need.  </p>
            <p> You will walk a couple of 100 meters and a screen will show how you place you foot in the shoes you have tested. </p>
            <p> Based on that you can choose new choes and will determine again if the shoes fit. </p>
            <p>Eventually you will have some good data which shoes will fit the best. The data will be sent via email.</p>
            <footer>
                <p> These shops are everywhere! In the USA and The Netherlands, you name it!</p>
                <p><a href="https://www.run4free.nl/"> More info? Click here</a></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="https://21run.com/eu/">
                <img class="img-inno" id="img1" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/male-athlete-running-on-tartan-track-royalty-free-image-1624297569.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.245xw,0&resize=640:*" alt="Running, copyright belongs to runner's world">
                </a>
        </div>
    </article>

    <article>
        <div class="left">
            <header class="inno">
                Innovation 2, Bowling
            </header>
            <p>This one could be a little bit silly, but it is a good innovation. I am talking about the Computerized Scoring Bowling.</p>
            <p> A computer will focus on the score, while you can focus on the bowling aspect and don't have to count your scores. </p>
            <p>These small innovations have a impact about our daily life without you aven noticing.</p>

            <footer>
                Fun Fact: The risk of a false score went down drasticly after this invention. 
                <a href="https://www.bowlingcentrum.nl/">Make a reservation for bwoling here. </a>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <a href="https://www.etsy.com/nl/listing/1052730525/aangepaste-airbrushed-bowling-ball?gpla=1&gao=1&">
            <img class="img-inno" src="https://cdn.bleacherreport.net/images_root/slides/photos/000/995/723/83452843_display_image.jpg?1307417974" alt="Bowling, Copyright belongs to bleacherreport.com">
        </a>
        </div>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Flexbox

That is the html code

```
<article>
    <p>Text</p>
    <img src=""/>
</article>
```

and that css

```
article {
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
```

then you can put spacing with margin and padding on your p or img and you can align your content, too

don't use float anymore, that's not modern coding style

read more about flexbox, there is a nice guide at css-tricks.com